# Post a mosaic of photos on Facebook timeline with /me/feed

Tags: php, facebook

I would like my application to post on the timeline a mosaic of 4 or 8 pictures as it is done with the "Photos" box (see an example below, I have hidden the photos as they are personal):

[image: Photos box from Facebook]
Using the Facebook API I can add a normal post to the timeline like this:

```
try
{
    $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST',
        array(
          'link' => 'www.freemages.fr',
          'message' => 'Posting with the PHP SDK!'
        ));
    echo "Post ID: ".$ret_obj["id"];
}
catch(FacebookApiException $e)
{
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array(
       'scope' => 'publish_stream'
       )); 
    echo "Veuillez vous <a href=\"".$login_url."\">identifier</a>";
    error_log($e->getType());
    error_log($e->getMessage());
}
```

However I dont see in the documentation if there is a way to do as explained. I don't really need to upload thumbnails of the pictures on the FB account, i just want to display them in a square format grouped by 4 per row on the timeline (for instance I could generate HTML code to create this layout but it does not seem possible).

Thanks for your tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like you need to read up on the open graph https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/ This is where you create custom objects,actions and aggregations and you can then prompt your users to add their activity to it. I think it does require submitting to facebook first though. I'd suggest reading the above link and seeing if you can get that to work. It's more of a box that appears on the profile timeline rather than in the feed.

At the moment you can find a step-by-step tutorial here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/

Comment: That helped a lot thanks! I was not looking at the right place and indeed I had to go for an open graph solution